# How to shorten: Environmental data, geospatial data, business data

Tags: lists

I have the sentence "These data sets span domains such as environmental data, geospatial data, business data". 
If I remove the repeated data i.e. "These data sets span domains such as environmental, geospatial, business data" does it then mean the same as the above sentence?

Comment: Why not? *Environmental* and *geospatial* are adjectives, and therefore will be naturally carried forward to the nearest noun, *data.* There's no problem either of grammar or of readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it means the same, but it is a little confusing to parse.  Sarah's suggestion is far better.

= edited to add =

"These data sets span domains such as environmental, geospatial, business data" is incorrect in more than one way.  You need a conjunction (I recommend "or") between "geospatial," and "business". Data is not a domain; it is contained in a domain. And it's not immediately clear that environmental, geospatial, and business are all adjectives applied to "data"; on first reading, it appears that the list is [environmental], [geospatial], and [business data].  Any time readers need to read something twice to understand it, it's poorly written.

Data sets of different natures such as environmental, geospatial, or business, may be employed.

Comment: I have added a bit more context, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

"Data from fields including: environmental, geospatial, and business."

Comment: That's not grammatical. Check the parts of speech.